# Docker container can't connect to each other

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have two containers in a docker compose, a Postgres DB and a Symfony PHP app.

From within the backend-app (PHP Symfony) I would like to execute commands that handle the DB connection, but none of the configs I try seem to work.
I added `expose` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844413/cant-connect-to-mongodb-container-from-other-docker-container) and also added a default network as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082755/cant-connect-to-other-containers-inside-docker-network)

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - 5431:5432
    expose:
      - "5431"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_DB: my_db
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  frontend:
    image: frontend-image:latest
    ports:
      - 8090:80
  backend-app:
    image: backend-app:latest
    links:
      - database
  backend-web:
    image: backend-web:latest
    ports:
      - 8091:80
    depends_on:
      - backend-app
      - database
networks:
  default:
```

Depending on the DB config in the Backend Container I get different error messages when executing `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` inside `backend-app`:

`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:password@database:5431/my_db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"`

leads to

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused. Is the server running on host "database" (172.21.0.2) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5431?

and
`DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:password@localhost:5431/my_db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"`

leads to

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5431?

Where am I wrong in my approaches?

Comment: Your port configuration for your database service is configured to respond to port 5431 on the **host** port, and 5432 on the **container** port. Change your `DATABASE_URL` connection string to use port 5432 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get to choose what the container expose inside the internal docker network created by compose.

[The postgress image exposes the port 5432](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/38841304ddd06dd3b39cc080b2c8fce5a5be8e52/11/Dockerfile#L217), so your `expose: 5431` instruction just exposes a port on which postgress is not listening, so it is useless.

So in between containers, you are stuck to using the port `5432` for postgress, unless you derive from the existing image, change the configuration there and expose the port you'd like.

The instruction below just change the port on which the container is exposed to the outside world, [as pointed by the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports)

```yaml
ports:
  - 5431:5432
```

This means that you are exposing the port `5432` of the container to the port `5431` of your host.

> Either specify both ports (`HOST:CONTAINER`), or just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen).

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports*</sup>

---

To sum up:

- your Symfony configuration should read:

  ```
  DATABASE_URL="postgresql://user:password@database:5432/my_db?serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
  ```
- the `expose` directive in your compose file is useless
- the `ports` directive as you wrote it there is only convenient if you want to connect from your host machine to the postgress container on a different port than the default one (i.e. because you already have a local postgress server running and, so the port is in use)

Comment: as for the ports I use, it is exactly like that, I have a local Postgres running. If I don't need to access it from outside, is the `ports` param even necessary?

Comment: Then, no, your postgress db will only be accessible inside the docker network created by compose. It can comes in handy if you have a DB tool that you would like to plug to your DB directly to execute SQL commands easily, but that is definitely not a must, of course.